# can i use custom lambda method in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, lambda

i have some methods like:

```
public static string ToOtherFormat (this string inp)
{
  // some code to change inp
  return inp;
}
```

and in my select i want to have code like this:

```
var DetailMembers = db.TB_Members
                      .Where(x=> x.FName == obj.ToOtherFormat())
                      .Select( x=> new { name = (x.FName.ToOtherFormat() + " " + x.LName) , x.ActCode });
```

i try and just have error. is it possible?
 
thanks!
i receive this error in simple convert to integer

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

with this code

```
 .Where(x => x.MemberID == Convert.ToInt32(Hmemid.Hash_two_Decrypt())
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are querying against the database. Your current query will get translated into SQL query and since SQL doesn't recognize your function that is why you get error.

You may get the data from the tables using a query without that function and then later do the formatting on the result set.

Comment: before entity i use LINQ, in LINQ i use similar query and they were worked fine. but i receive just error

Comment: yes i do that now, i convert them before and after query, its not wisely. but thanks to your help.

Comment: the lamda expression does not convert to SQL, that's why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

i found it on use `.AsEnumerable()` method like:

```
var DetailMembers = db.TB_Members.AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(x=> x.FName == obj.ToOtherFormat())
                      .Select( x=> new { name = (x.FName.ToOtherFormat() + " " + x.LName) , x.ActCode });
```